# Is there a c++ library to include flash videos in a cross-platform application?

Tags: c++, flash

I'm developing a c++ applicaton using Qt, and we're looking to include swf files. Is there a way I can include swfs in my application? I'm open to different solutions for windows, mac, and linux, but a single cross-platform solution would be best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebKit (in sufficiently recent versions of Qt; it's included for sure in 4.4 and 4.5) and embed the flash animations via that.  This depends on having a flash plugin installed and accessible to WebKit, but it should be workable on Mac, Windows, and Linux (with either gnash/swfdec or Adobe's plugin).

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but [Scaleform GFx](https://www.scaleform.com/products/gfx) provides a cross-platform Flash player.  It can work with multiple different kinds of renderers, including but not limited to DirectX and OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [swfdec](http://swfdec.freedesktop.org/wiki/) or [gnash](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/), however I don't know how portable they will be. It might be worth checking out the [VLC source](http://wiki.videolan.org/Flash_Video) as well. To ensure cross-platform however I would suggest going with a more standard, even better open, video format.  An example of using gnash with GTK is below:

http://blog.tomeuvizoso.net/2009/04/embed-flash-movies-with-gnash-in-your.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to try to run the plugin version of Flash Player in your application. Projects like [Screenweaver](http://screenweaver.org/) have implemented their own Netscape plugin API wrappers to do this.

You can also look at [NSPluginWrapper](http://gwenole.beauchesne.info//en/projects/nspluginwrapper) project, they have a standalone plugin player implemented, which you possibly might be able to adapt into your own project.